# How to get the general form of this infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Please, how to find the general forms of the two parts, real and imaginary, of the following infinite series ?

$$-1-\frac{3}{5}Ax^2 -\frac{3}{7}A^2 x^4-\frac{3}{9}A^3 x^6-\frac{3}{11}A^4 x^8-\frac{3}{13}A^5 x^{10}+ \cdots +i\left(\frac{4}{15}A x^3+\frac{92}{175} A^2 x^5+\frac{56}{75} A^3 x^7+\frac{4520}{4851}A^4 x^9+\cdots\right)$$

Where $A, x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Real part seems clear enough...as to the imaginary part:  is $\frac {56}{75}$ the reduced form of something else?  If so, can we see the original?  Also...any information on the source of these numbers might help.

Comment: This series is the result of the expansion of a complex infinite continued fraction. I get the term `56/75` directly from this expansion.

Comment: Here is the next terms of the imaginary part : $-i\left(\frac{4}{15}A x^3+\frac{92}{175} A^2 x^5+\frac{56}{75} A^3 x^7+\frac{4520}{4851}A^4 x^9+\frac{114308}{105105}A^5  x^{11}+\frac{4996}{4095}A^6  x^{13}+\frac{15321776}{11486475} A^7  x^{15}+\cdots\right)$

Comment: Not seeing anything, sorry!  I am surprised that the denominators do not steadily increase...but I've tried looking at ${75n}$ say, where $175<75n<4581$ and that doesn't get me anywhere.

Comment: @lulu, Please what is the general form of this new infinite series : $-1-\frac{3}{5}Ax^2 -\frac{3}{7}A^2 x^4-\frac{3}{9}A^3 x^6-\frac{3}{11}A^4 x^8-\frac{3}{13}A^5 x^{10}+ \cdots +i\left(\frac{22}{15}A x^3+\frac{56}{25} A^2 x^5+\frac{206}{75} A^3 x^7+\cdots\right)$

Comment: As with the other, the imaginary part eludes me.  Do you have any reason to imagine that there is a simple form?

Comment: It's only the expansion of tne infinite continued fraction. This is the simplest form.